# C++ wstring - Error reading characters of strings | Happens after the 10th character

Tags: c++, wstring

I am asking for information to save onto the database like their username and stuff, you can use up to 10 characters perfectly fine, the `wstring` holds it and I can use it how I like, but if a user were to type 11 characters it would all of a sudden say `"Error reading characters of strings"`.

At first I thought I didn't have a big enough space for `GetWindowText` so I pumped that up, I didn't know if you can change the `wstring` capacity so that is why I am asking here.

Why is `wstring` only working with 10 or less characters? Thanks!

```
case WM_COMMAND: {

    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case IDB_REGISTERACCOUNT: {
            std::wstringstream SQLStatementStream;
            std::wstring SQLUsername;
            std::wstring SQLPassword;

            //Get user information than store in wide Strings
            GetWindowText(hUserNameRegister, &SQLUsername[0], 50);
            GetWindowText(hPasswordRegister, &SQLPassword[0], 50);

            std::wstring SQLStatement = SQLStatementStream.str();

            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think your wstrings have 50 characters allocated?

Comment: Nothing makes me think it, I just pumped it to 50 to reset it back to 18 later, for testing purposes. Here we go again, negative votes but no one wants to tell me what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is essentially saying, "I am giving you the address of the first character of this string, start writing to it indiscriminately."  This is going to be a bad time.  What you need to do is first allocate an actual buffer to use to store the result, then if you wanted in the wstring, you can use the wstring's '=' operator to do the proper assignment.

something like:

```
WCHAR temp[50];
GetWindowText(hUserNameRegister, temp, 50);
SQLUsername = temp
```

Comment: Alright the reason I did it with wstring is because when I posted it with wchar before, everyone bashes on me like "This is c++ why can you not do this with wstring" blah blah blah. But this works so thank you!

Comment: The difficulty comes through mixing C APIs like GetWindowText.  They are often wrapped so calling them makes sense.  This is really a C-style solution to a C problem.

Comment: Big upvote. When in C, use C. If you do this often and have to politely integrate someone else's C your C++, consider writing a wrapper.

Comment: Using wstring is fine, but you need to use a wstring of 50 characters (or 18, or whatever you pass to GetWindowText) not an empty string.

Comment: @KirkSpaziani, the Windows API is a C++ API, not C, so that's misleading and unhelpful. There is no problem using `wstring` for this purpose, you just need to ensure the string is large enough to hold the 50 characters that might get written into it.

Comment: "The Win32 API (also known as the Windows API) is a C-based framework for creating Windows applications. For more information about the Win32 API" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You write past the end of your string. This causes undefined behaviour.

Only use `&x[0]` on a standard library string when you are in read-only mode, or if you are writing but not going to change the length of the string.

You should have written:

```
wchar_t SQLUsername[50] = {};
GetWindowTextW(hUserNameRegister, SQLUsername, 50);
```

Then you can convert to `wstring` if you wanted with `std::wstring wsSQLUsername = SQLUsername;` - however your code never actually uses your `wstring`s before they go out of scope so perhaps you have some other misconceptions too.

Comment: There would be no problem using `wstring buf; buf.resize(50);` and passing `&buf[0]` to the function.

Comment: Alright thank you, I tried to look up wstring and information about it with what exactly &SqlUsername[0] means and I couldn't find it anywhere so I didn't know what it would do exactly. I thought remembered when I read my book C++ Primer Plus 6 calling to the first element in the array was the address of the whole string, but obviously I do not believe that would be correct.

Comment: @JonathanWakely you'd have to make another `resize` call afterwards to get the string length back in sync with the position of the null terminator.. kinda ugly. The decision would depend on how the string was going to be used I suppose

Comment: @TylerCorkery it is the address of  the whole string, but your string is empty. When you say `std::wstring SQLUsername;` that creates an empty string. So you get the address of the whole empty string. You still can't write 50 characters to an empty string.